# Rails, Spork and debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, spork, guard

I use spork with Guard + Rspec but the debugger doesn't work as expected:

- I added `require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'` just after the `require 'spork'`
- it properly stops on `debugger` breakpoints...
- ... but I can't access `irb`, it spits: `Command is available only in local mode.`

Do you know how to get around this?

Thanks,

---

PS: of course I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732253/cant-get-rspec-spork-and-debugger-to-play-nice) but it's a bit outdated and doesn't work.

PS2: I'd like to avoid using [this](https://github.com/irohiroki/guard-spork-ruby-debug-sample).

PS3: : I also posted this as an issue [here](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/158).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using [pry](http://pry.github.com/), it is so much more awesome.  I include it in my `spec_helper` file (works with Test::Unit too) and can do `binding.pry` within my tests to *[essentially pry into objects](http://pry.github.com/)*.  Works fine with Guard/Spork/RSpec/Cucumber/Spinach for me.

Pry has long since replaced IRB as my default REPL.

Comment: Interesting. What do you exactly include and where please?

Comment: Are you using `RSpec` or `Test::Unit`?  There's a screencast on this as well.  [Pry with Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails)

Comment: Rspec. +1 for your help so far.

Comment: Take a look here for my config: https://github.com/bsodmike/CoreApp/blob/source/spec/spec_helper.rb

Comment: You can then just do `binding.pry` in any test and see 'magic' happen when you run the spec =)  Watch the awesome casts on pry.

Comment: Just wondering: did you keep config.cache_classes to true in your test.rb file (leading to spork restarts) or did you set it to false (which crashes capybara)?

Comment: I don't recall touching that option. Some more info on [config.cache_classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272978/config-cache-classes-false-messing-up-rspec-tests)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in my app, while reaching a `binding.pry` line, I see ugly lines with `lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:414:in 'readline'
TypeError: wrong argument type DRb::DRbObject (expected File)`. But it works in your app. I'll search again but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Indeed, I realized that using ree and not 1.9.2 could be the problem.: even your app is failing in this case.

Comment: @apneadiving, could you file an issue on https://github.com/pry/pry/issues with instructions on how to reproduce? thanks!

Comment: apneadiving as you realised I've only tested that 'test' app against 1.9.2; as per @banister this seems to be a ree/pry issue.  I've not had any issues with pry from Rails 3.0.8 to 3.1.1

Comment: @banister, done here: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/345. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: The `pry` team are pretty awesome - you can find them in #pry on irc.freenode.net too =)

Answer (score 1):

OP's bug report leads [here](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/142), which [advises](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/142#issuecomment-2385287) to turn off interactive mode by starting guard like so:

```
bundle exec guard -i
```

This worked for me.